# How to get Atom's less-linter to understand Webpack's less-loader paths

Tags: webpack, less, atom-editor

I have a react/webpack SPA that uses less. I wanted to be able to import a global variables file ('globals.less') in any .less file without having to worry about relative paths ('../../../styles/globals.less', etc) so I changed my webpack less rule to specify paths:

```
        {
          loader: 'less-loader',
          options: {
            paths: [
              path.resolve(ROOT_PATH, 'node_modules'),
              path.resolve(ROOT_PATH, 'src/styles')
            ]
          }
        }
```

Which works great -- now in any subfolder's .less file I can just go `@import 'globals'` and I get my variables.

But I'm using Atom with the 'linter-less' plugin, and it red-underline's that import statement with the message `globals.less wasn't found. Tried [...]` -- In the less-linter package settings in Atom there's an 'Include Path' line item that says "Set include paths. Separate by ','" and I've tried variations on src/styles, ./src/styles, 'src/styles', '/src/styles' with no success. My folder structure looks like ROOT > src > styles > globals.less. I'm wondering if anyone knows a better way or if I'm just using paths incorrectly in those settings.

Comment: Or, alternatively, what's the best way to make global variables in less available via webpack and have the linter ignore variables it 'can't find'?

Comment: I'm not sure in Atom, but in VSCode it's pretty easy https://blog.andrewray.me/autocomplete-es-modules-webpack-vscode/

Answer (score 0):

Turns out you have to put the *full* path in the settings, e.g., Users/username/dev/projectname/etc... Maybe there's a way to make paths relative to the project but I doubt it